# How to keep the received odd number of buttons from baseAdapter in triangular shape in Android?

Tags: java, android, baseadapter, android-gridview

I am trying to set the received odd number of buttons from `BaseAdapter` in `GridView` like triangular shape like in case 1 of the attached pic. I am getting a good place for even number of buttons that received from `BaseAdapter`. I have attached the photos.

[image]

Comment: how you want to show? can you please explain, or add a hypothetical screenshot?

Comment: You may want to use FlexLayout

Comment: I want to achieve the buttons like CASE 1 that I have posted a screenshot

Answer (score -1):

Use `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"` for parent layout containing those buttons